# Nested Interface alternative in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Okay I have an interface which has few interfaces in it and the code looks like this in Kotlin

```
interface IStreamRepository : IBaseRepository {

interface OnAddStreamCallback {
    fun onSuccess()
    fun onError(message: String)
}

interface OnGetAllStreamsCallback {
    fun onSuccess(streams: ArrayList<Stream>)
    fun onError(message: String)
}

interface OnGetStreamByNameCallback {
    fun onSuccess(stream: Stream)
    fun onError(message: String)
}

interface OnDeleteStreamCallback {
    fun onSuccess()
    fun onError(message: String)
}
}
```

and when I try to do

```
getAllStreamsCallBack = IStreamRepository.OnGetAllStreamsCallback() {
    //and override methods in OnGetAllStreamsCallback interface 
}
```

the compiler throws the following error `OnGetAllStreamsCallback does not have constructors`, How can I solve this issue?

Comment: That question concerns annotations ([`@interface`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918393/whats-the-difference-between-interface-and-interface-in-java))

Comment: Please next time ensure that problem really exists before posting a question.

Answer (score 5):

The linked question is related to nested annotation classes.
You can nest interfaces without problems:

```
interface Outer {
    interface Inner
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val o = object : Outer {}
    val i = object : Outer.Inner {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> when I try to do getAllStreamsCallBack = IStreamRepository.OnGetAllStreamsCallback() { and override methods in OnGetAllStreamsCallback interface } the compiler throws the following error OnGetAllStreamsCallback dose not have constructors

You'd get the same error with a non-nested interface. The syntax is `getAllStreamsCallBack = object : IStreamRepository.OnGetAllStreamsCallback { ... }`. If it was a class, you'd need `()` after the name, for an interface you don't.