# error: elements in annotation type declarations cannot declare formal parameters

Tags: android, interface, compiler-errors, rx-java, retrofit2

I am an amateur in android development. I am trying to post/send data to server using retrofit and rxjava in my android project. I was following this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845).

But in the interface section of the code, I get 2 compiler errors and the code doesn't compile.

```
error: elements in annotation type declarations cannot declare formal parameters
error: invalid type for element {0} of annotation type
```

The interface looks like in the given link. Nevertheless, I'm just posting it.

```
public @interface APIService {

@POST("/posts")
@FormUrlEncoded
Observable<Post> savePost(@Field("title") String title,
                             @Field("body") String body,
                             @Field("userId") long userId);
}
```

I am calling it like:

```
mAPIService.savePost(title, body,1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

where `private APIService mAPIService;`

The Post Model is given below:

```
public class Post {

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("body")
@Expose
private String body;
@SerializedName("userId")
@Expose
private Integer userId;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Post{" +
            "title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", body='" + body + '\'' +
            ", userId=" + userId +
            ", id=" + id +
            '}';
   }
}
```

Why is this error coming? And what's the way around?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem lies in `@interface`. If you follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918417/5658251), then you'll see that it must be replaced with simply `interface`.