# Errors while binding a library with Java annotations

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, java-annotations, xamarin-binding

Fellow developers,

I'm binding this library:

https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial

But I have faced two issues while generating the control:

[image]

The first one, I had an idea how to do it I added the following code in the Metadata.xml:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.leinardi.android.speeddial']/class[@name='SpeedDialView']/method[@name='getBehavior']" name="GetBehavior"></attr>
```

But I still get the error: **'SpeedDialView' does not implement interface member.**

The other problem, I have a guessing that is connected to the annotations (I already added this package [Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations/)) since the function that is not working is the following one:

```
@ExpansionMode
public int getExpansionMode() {
    return mInstanceState.mExpansionMode;
}
```

Because later, there is an "interface" (not exactly from my research [What's the difference between interface and @interface in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918417/2889347)) created with this name and probably is not being renamed properly:

```
@Retention(SOURCE)
@IntDef({TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT})
public @interface ExpansionMode {
    int TOP = 0;
    int BOTTOM = 1;
    int LEFT = 2;
    int RIGHT = 3;
}
```

Any idea how can I fix these 2 issues? I attached my [project](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/5o/3zlwv0dzasfa.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the functionality of that library you are trying to create bindings for, I see that there's many alternative you can use instead of doing it from scratch, like adding the [FAB.XamarinAndroid](http://%20https://github.com/fabionuno/FloatingActionButton-Xamarin.Android) nuget package. Let me know if there's something specific your are looking for that doesnt fit with the Nuget

Comment: Hi Sammer, you mean like mine? I have bound a similar one too: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin-OneMoreFabMenu

What I'm trying to do is to fix the library and learn how to fix it that's why I asked because I want to learn how to do it. If you can help me is to provide some guide or  tips how to fix it :).

Comment: Haha nice! Didn't notice. Alright, my answer is definitely not what you are looking for