# Room Junction syntax in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In the following example, `FolderItem::class` belongs to the `value` property of `Junction`, even though it is not explicitly stated:

```
class FolderWithItems(
        @Embedded
        val folder: Folder,
        @Relation(
                associateBy = Junction(
                        FolderItem::class,
                        parentColumn = "folder_id",
                        entityColumn = "item_id"
                ),
                parentColumn = "id",
                entityColumn = "id"
        )
        val items: List<Item>
)
```

It compiles and runs the same as if I were to write out:

`value = FolderItem::class`

What is the Kotlin principle/rule/language feature that allows you to not have to specify `value =` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Just like in Java, a special case is the value parameter; its value can be specified without an explicit name](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#java-annotations)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I think what confused me is that `Junction` has '@interface' in its class header which I was previously not familiar with, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918417/11566289) helped me understand what that means. Also, what's interesting is that if I remove for example `parentColumn = `, then Android Studio says "only named arguments are available for Java annotations", yet it doesn't complain when `value =` is removed.

Comment: @glucaio Actually, if Junction is an annotation here (which makes sense and I overlooked), then my answer was incorrect. I've fixed it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for fixing. I had no idea. It all makes sense now.